# Vue: proxy framework component with v-model

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to proxy `<vue-date-picker/>`, which exposes a Date-based v-model in a way that it can be used with Dayjs (which we use across the app) instead. How can I achieve this? I am on latest Vue with composition API.

I know I need to use @update:model-value and :model-value to split the 2-way data binding into 2x1-way and have a conversion in between, but I don't know how to pass a v-model value into a ref() and at the same time emit events which can be consumed as a v-model in a parent component. I tried out many variations, my current code looks like this:

```
const convertedValue = ref(dayjs(props.value).toDate());
watchEffect(() => {
  convertedValue.value = dayjs(props.value).toDate();
});
watchEffect(() => {
  emit('update:value', dayjs(convertedValue.value));
});
...
<vue-date-picker :model-value="convertedValue" />
```

But it just does not work. This should be a pretty common use-case, no? What can I do?

---

EDIT: thanks to the answer from Alexander and a colleague of mine, I managed to get it working like this:

```
const value = computed(() => convertToDatePicker(props.modelValue));
const emit = defineEmits<{
  'update:model-value': [date: dayjs.Dayjs | null];
}>();
function handleEmit(event: ModelValue) {
  emit('update:model-value', convertToDayjs(event));
}
...
:model-value="value"
@update:model-value="handleEmit"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard way to use `computed()`:

```
// use it as v-model for the input in the template
const value = computed({
  get(){
    return dayjs(props.value).toDate();
  },
  set(val){
    emit('update:value', dayjs(val));
  }
  
});
```

I also suggest to use `modelValue` instead of `value` as the prop so you can bind your proxy component with clean `v-model` too.

[In the Vue 3.3 a macro `defineModel()` is available](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3#definemodel) which accepts the same get/set as the second parameter.
It is marked as experimental, [stable in 3.4](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-4#definemodel-is-now-stable)

Comment: Thank you, this indeed provided me some guidance and I managed to get my code working (see the edit). Using get/set and the reference to defineModel did not help though - I have created an issue for this on github: https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/10103

Comment: @Phil here's docs for defineModel, maybe could help: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#definemodel

Comment: It didn't solve my problem completely, but since I found a solution (see my edit), my question is not relevant anymore. I also figured out why my code is not working thanks to the response from Evan You in the issue. When I use this inside computed `set: (val) => (model.value = convertToDayjs(val))` I get no update, despite `@update:model-value="console.log($event)"` logging the event from the template. For now I will accept and close this question, but I am still a bit confused tbh - I just can't find a solution without manually defining emits instead of overriding default update:model-value